# Populate acf-field, depending on block name

Tags: functions, hooks

I have an acf *select* "global_fargtema" for all blocks

what i am trying to do is, if a block name is == "acf/full-width-talker"
populate the field "global_fargtema" with $object->ID = "1"; $object->post_title ="Full width talker";
if a block name is == "acf/usp" $object->ID = "1"; $object->post_title ="USP";

There cane be multiple blocks on one page, any idea on how this can be achived?

```
       function acf_load_theme_field_choices($field)
    $field['choices'] = array(
        'custom'    => 'My Custom Choice',
        'custom_2'  => 'My Custom Choice 2'
    );
    return $field;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
    $post = get_post();
    if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        if ( $blocks[0]['blockName'] === 'acf/full-width-talker' ) {
      
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=global_fargtema', 'acf_load_theme_field_choices');
        }
    }
```

but it did not work

Comment: Does the answer solved your problem. Do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `get_post()` using null. Try to retrieve the post individually. Use `get_post(get_the_ID())` to get the post content.

```
$post = get_post(get_the_ID());
if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
    if ( $blocks[0]['blockName'] === 'acf/full-width-talker' ) {
  
    }
}
```